# Python list comprehension optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, python-collections

I have used during a problem this piece of code to retrieve the count of each element in a list :

```py
nums = [1,1,3,2,3,3,4,1,1,4,2,3,3,2,1,3,4,1,2]
print([nums.count(num) for num in set(nums)])
```

This code works well but doesn't look like to be as efficient as this code :

```py
from collections import Counter
nums = [1,1,3,2,3,3,4,1,1,4,2,3,3,2,1,3,4,1,2]
counter = Counter(nums)
print(counter.values())
```

Can someone explains to me why is the `collections` library is more faster than the vanilla list comprehension ?

Comment: Your implementation is `O(n**2)`, `Counter` is `O(n)`.

Comment: `Counter` makes one pass through the list, updating counts as it goes. Your implementation makes  a full pass through the entire list for *every* element of the list.

Comment: It's not really about the list comprehension, but the use of `nums.count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code with `Counter` is roughly equivalent to:

```py
def counter_v1(seq):
    counts = {}
    for x in seq:
        counts[x] = counts.get(x, 0) + 1
    return counts
```

The code with `.count` is roughly equivalent to:

```py
def count(seq, x):
    c = 0
    for y in seq:
        if y == x:
            c += 1
    return c

def counter_v2(seq):
    counts = {}
    for x in set(seq):
        counts[x] = count(seq, x)
    return counts
```

As you can see, function `counter_v1` iterates through the sequence once, with a single for-loop. By contrast, function `counter_v2` iterates through the sequence *once per distinct element*, with a for-loop inside another for-loop.

The runtime of `counter_v1` will be roughly proportional to `len(seq)`, whereas the runtime of `counter_v2` will be roughly proportional to `len(seq) * len(set(seq))`, which is usually much bigger.